# Kruskal-Wallis test in r: Error in ordering groups by median

Tags: r, median, posthoc

I would appreciate help in solving the following problem. I'm conducting the Kruskal-Wallis test with within-groups (4) data, and following the instructions here: http://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_08.html. One step is ordering the groups by median:

```
$senseofpresence$Condition = factor(senseofpresence$condition, levels=c("A", "B", $"C", "D", "E"))
```

However, when ordering the groups by median, I receive the following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Condition", value = integer(0)) : 
>   replacement has 0 rows, data has 128

I'm unsure what causes the error and whether the K-W test and the Dunn posthoc tests work regardless of the error message. The code and the results are below. I'd appreciate your help in resolving the issue. This is my very first post on StackOverflow, and I'm also very new to R.

```
> senseofpresence$Condition = factor(senseofpresence$Condition,
>+                       levels=unique(senseofpresence$Condition))
> senseofpresence$PresentPlace1.f = factor(senseofpresence$PresentPlace1,
>+                        ordered = TRUE)
> xtabs( ~ Condition + PresentPlace1.f,
>+        data = senseofpresence)
         PresentPlace1.f
>Condition  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
        A  0  0  0  2  5 11 10
        B  1  1  1  1 11  9  1
        C  2  3  5  3  5  8  1
        D  0  2  0  1 10  7  6
        E  1  4  1  1  7  4  4
> 
> XT = xtabs( ~ Condition + PresentPlace1.f,
>+             data = senseofpresence)
> 
> prop.table(XT,
>+            margin = 1)
         PresentPlace1.f
>Condition          1          2          3          4          5          6          >7
>        A 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.07142857 0.17857143 0.39285714 >0.35714286
>        B 0.04000000 0.04000000 0.04000000 0.04000000 0.44000000 0.36000000 >0.04000000
        C 0.07407407 0.11111111 0.18518519 0.11111111 0.18518519 0.29629630 >0.03703704
>        D 0.00000000 0.07692308 0.00000000 0.03846154 0.38461538 0.26923077 >0.23076923
        E 0.04545455 0.18181818 0.04545455 0.04545455 0.31818182 0.18181818 >0.18181818
> library (lattice)
> 
> histogram( ~ PresentPlace1.f | Condition,
>+           data=senseofpresence,
>+           layout=c(1,3)  
>+           )
> 
> library(FSA)
> Summarize(PresentPlace1 ~ Condition,
>+           data=senseofpresence, 
>+           digits=3)
>  Condition  n  mean    sd min   Q1 median Q3 max
1         A 28 6.036 0.922   4 5.75    6.0  7   7
2         B 25 5.040 1.338   1 5.00    5.0  6   7
3         C 27 4.259 1.745   1 3.00    5.0  6   7
4         D 26 5.462 1.334   2 5.00    5.5  6   7
5         E 22 4.682 1.887   1 3.25    5.0  6   7
> kruskal.test(PresentPlace1 ~ Condition,
>+              data = senseofpresence)

>   Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

>data:  PresentPlace1 by Condition
>Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 19.754, df = 4, p-value = 0.0005585

> 
> senseofpresence$Condition = factor(senseofpresence$condition, 
>+                       levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
>Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Condition", value = integer(0)) : 
>  replacement has 0 rows, data has 128
> 
> levels(senseofpresence$Condition)
>[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
> 
> library(FSA)
> 
> DT = dunnTest(PresentPlace1 ~ Condition,
>+               data=senseofpresence,
>+               method="bh")      # Adjusts p-values for multiple comparisons;
> DT
>Dunn (1964) Kruskal-Wallis multiple comparison
>  p-values adjusted with the Benjamini-Hochberg method.

>   Comparison          Z      P.unadj        P.adj
>1       A - B  2.7334681 6.267119e-03 0.0208903954
>2       A - C  4.1353289 3.544465e-05 0.0003544465
>3       B - C  1.3087557 1.906171e-01 0.2723101491
>4       A - D  1.6053479 1.084173e-01 0.2168345127
>5       B - D -1.1242981 2.608866e-01 0.3261082038
>6       C - D -2.4681705 1.358056e-02 0.0339514018
>7       A - E  2.9473396 3.205210e-03 0.0160260486
>8       B - E  0.2995078 7.645526e-01 0.7645526055
>9       C - E -0.9599074 3.371018e-01 0.3745575517
>10      D - E  1.3893854 1.647156e-01 0.2745259737
```

Comment: Where do you order by median? The first code block doesn't do that. Possible sources of error are the factor level in your first code block `$"C"`, and swapping bewteen `Condition` and `condition`

Comment: Please show us your actual data (or a small working representative sample) to be able to help you

Comment: Thank you. It was the swapping between Condition and condition